# python numpy how to increase the index given

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, tuples

I have this method location which finds the location of a piece on the 2d array board and I want to change the index to the position next to it.

```
def location(self, board):
    x = np.argwhere(board == 1)
    print(x)
    return x

x = self.location(board + 1)
```

Comment: You've looked at `x`, which is a 2d array (2 columns, right?).  Since it's an array, you can do normal math on it, such as add 1 to `x[0,1]`.  The  result of `y=np.where(board==1)` is easier to use, as in `board[y]`, but the same information is in `argwhere`.

Comment: The code posted isn't indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly interpreting your question, you just need to move the +1 out of the parentheses:

```
def location(self, board):
    x = np.argwhere(board == 1)
    print(x)
    return x

x = self.location(board) + 1
```

What you're doing in the question is adding 1 to the board itself, not to the returned indices